# Why do sines and cosines form a basis, and can be considered a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, fourier-series

Many times I've seen that Fourier series are justified because we are thinking that the set of all functions of the form $\sin(ax)$ and $\cos(ax)$ form a vector space. A function can therefore be expressed as some coefficient and my base vector.

But I just don't see why the set of all $\sin(ax)$ and $\cos(ax)$ form a vector space. For example, they don't satisfy the condition of closure under addition because when I add two of these I'll get a $\phi$ term and I won't have a function of the form $\sin(ax)$ or $\cos(ax)$.

Aside from Fourier series I had this problem where I had to prove that the space of all functions with form $\sin(ax)$ and $\cos(ax)$ where orthogonal on the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. I don't think this is an actual vector space.

Thanks.

Comment: Do $(a,0)$ and $(0,a)$ 'form a vector space'? When you add them you get $\color{grey}{\phi=}(a,a)$ which doesn't have the form $(a,0)$ or $(0,a)$.

Comment: They don't form a vector space. I dont see your point :( . Are you saying that these functions do in fact not form a vector space? Thanks

Comment: All linear combinations of $\sin(ax)$ and $\cos(ax)$ form a vector space. A "vector" will thus have the form $p\sin(ax) + q\cos(ax)$, where _p_ and _q_ are real numbers.

Comment: I had a point, but I also had an ulterior motive in that I wanted to see how you understand the terminology in use. What is meant is that $\langle x\mapsto \sin(ax), x\mapsto \cos(ax)\rangle$ is a vector space for all $a\in \mathbb R$, (but $a\neq 0$ is probably implied). This is of course trivial because the notation $\langle \cdot \rangle$ immediately creates a vector space. Are you perhaps confused about how addition and scalar multiplication are defined?

Comment: I guess my confusion is that I think the set of all those functions do not form a vector space mostly because of the failure to fulfil the closure under addition (the $\phi$ term I mentioned). I think $ a$ can equal zero because that would be the first term on a fourier series, for example.

Comment: Getting back to my first comment, the set $\{(a,0), (0,a)\}$ isn't a vector space, this is correct. But $\langle (a,0), (0,a)\rangle$ is. This is what the text is (implicitly,I'll give you that), claiming. The set $\{x\mapsto \sin(ax), x\mapsto \cos(ax)\}$ doesn't form a vector space, but $\langle x\mapsto \sin(ax), x\mapsto \cos(ax)\rangle$. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: I don't , sorry. I've just been introduced to both linear algebra and fourier series.

Comment: @David Given a set $A$ (with an addition and a scalar multiplication), the symbol $\langle A\rangle$ denotes the smallest vector space containing $A$, also called the vector space spanned by $A$. If you wish, you can interpret that the book is saying that given the functions $x\mapsto \sin(ax)$ and $x\mapsto \cos(ax)$ which I'll denote by $f$ and $g$, respectively, the set $\{\alpha f+\beta g\colon \alpha, \beta\in \mathbb R\}$ is a vector space.

Comment: So really the vector space is "The set of all linear combinations of $sin(ax)$ and $cos(ax)$"?

Comment: Yes, that's what is meant. Similarly $\{(a,0), (0,a)\}$ isn't a vector space, but the linear combinations of $(a,0)$ and $(0,a)$ is.

Comment: Thanks Git. If you add some answer below I'll be glad to accept as the answer.

Comment: If all else is clear, I suggest you just delete your question. If there's something else you don't understand, then consider updating your question (without changing it too radically).

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question (which was just bumped $9$ years later) can be marked as answered:

The confusion was cleared up in the comments. The sines and cosines themselves don’t form a vector space, but the set of functions they generate, qua construction, does form a vector space.